# Как можно сворачивать полноэкранное приложение?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как можно сворачивать полноэкранное приложение в Delphi 7 при потере фокуса? Пользуюсь компонентом `TApplicationEvents` - событиями `onDeactivate` (сворачиваю) и `onActivate` (выполняю действия при разворачивании).

Проблема в том, что вслед за `onDeactivate` почему-то тут же возникает событие `onActivate`, и действия, которые должны были быть выполнены при разворачивании приложения, выполняются при его сворачивании. Как быть в такой ситуации?

Comment: простите, а при чем тут OpenGL?

Answer (score 1):

Да, если вызвать `Application.Minimize` в событии `OnDeactivate` то тут же получим событие `OnActivate`, поскольку сворачивание - это тоже действие над приложением, и оно вызывает это событие. При разворачивании обратно, нового события `OnActivate` не возникает.

Есть немного странное, но рабочее решение: на время вызова `Application.Minimize` отключить действия на событие `OnActivate`

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Deactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ApplicationEvents1.OnActivate := nil;
  Application.Minimize;
  ApplicationEvents1.OnActivate := ApplicationEvents1Activate;
end;
```